# Is it possible that dark matter is just a bunch of gravitational waves interacting with one another?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, gravitational-waves, dark-matter

Since stars and other objects are much closer to one another towards the centers of galaxies where dark matter tends to be found, it seems that it would follow that events forming gravitational waves (like LIGO detected) would occur more frequently. Since gravitational waves carry mass-energy, is it possible that a whole bunch of them interacting is responsible for all the mass that dark matter is said to be responsible for?

Comment: There are lots of reasons why this doesn't fit observations, but I think the simplest evidence that this doesn't work is the energy budget: the most efficient GW producers are BH-binaries, which emit (typically) $\sim 1\%$ of their mass-energy to GW.  Galaxies, however, have (typically) $10\times$ as much DM as normal matter (and this also seems to be a higher ratio for small galaxies, with few stars and BH).